# How to autowire a member variable inside a class which is not maintained by spring container?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

In my jsp, I have a custom tag

```
 <ex:SelfService />
```

which intrun calls the java class

```
public class SelfServiceClass extends SimpleTagSupport{

@Autowired
 private ReloadablePropertyManagerImpl reloadableProperty;


public ReloadablePropertyManagerImpl getReloadableProperty() {
    return reloadableProperty;
}

public void setReloadableProperty(
        ReloadablePropertyManagerImpl reloadableProperty) {
    this.reloadableProperty = reloadableProperty;
}

public void doTag() throws IOException {
    JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
    out.println(getReloadableProperty().getPropertyValue("print.service"));
  }
}
```

And in my spring.xml I have configured the bean,

```
 <bean id="reloadableProperty" class="com.testing.portal.util.ReloadablePropertyManagerImpl" />
```

But I am getting null pointer exception when I call getPropertyValue() on reloadableProperty object.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Spring aware of **SelfServiceClass** class? It has to be. You either annotate it with @Component or it is returned by a @Configuration as a @Bean or include it as you did with reloadebleProperty in the xml, i.e.: make it a spring managed bean

Comment: I annotated SelfServiceClass class with Component and added bean in xml like this,
<bean id="SelfServiceClass" class="com.testing.portal.tag.SelfServiceClass" /> Still I am getting the null pointer. 
Regarding making spring aware of SelfServiceClass, can you explain it in details please. I didnt get that completely. I am very new to spring

Comment: @Prasad this means that that field does not get autowired. Do you have component-scan option in your xml? Go through spring docs and read them...

Comment: I did a quick read on component-scan. I added <context:component-scan base-package="com.testing.portal.tag" /> in my xml and ran it again. Still its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Since your class is not managed by Spring you have to load the `ReloadablePropertyManagerImpl` from the application context by yourself. In order to do so you should create a class which implements `ApplicationContextAware` with a static getter for the context.

See more in this [sample](http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/08/23/gaining-access-to-the-spring-context-in-non-spring-managed-classes/).